# React : Iframe src linked by react-router instead of open file in public folder

Tags: reactjs, iframe, react-router

I use iframe to open page store in my public folder.

It work properly when I run on my localhost. but after upload to server, The path runs by react-router instead of open the file.

Here's how my iframe look like. (The path is dynamic. program and schedule will replace with name)

```
<iframe src='/program/schedule/index.html'></iframe>
```

In my router. I even add /play/ to separate normal path and router link. But still not working.

Here's how the router that hijack the path look like.

```
<Route path='/play/:programUrl/:scheduleUrl' render={(props)=>
    <Link to={'/play/'}><img className='home-logo' src='/img/full-logo-small.png' /></Link>
}/>
```